# Help me to get the expiration date 

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, pdf

Greetings for the day!.

Is there any way to get the **expiration date of PDF files**?

Kindly give me any reference link or tutorial to get the expiration date from the PDF files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a date in the metadata of a PDF file but you cannot 'expire' a PDF file